# What is the simplest way to factor the following polynomial $x^4-8x^2+x+12$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> What is the simplest  way  to factor the following  polynomial  $$x^4-8x^2+x+12$$ ?

Note : I already knew the factorization which is 
$$(x^2-x-3)(x^2+x-4)$$

I need the way to get that

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean 'simplest'. For example, I beleive it's really simple to find the roots of it (its only a quartic) and from there go to the two quadratics but I don't think thats what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the algorithm described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_cubic#Factoring_quartic_polynomials). In your case, the resolvent of the polynomial is $x^3-16x^2+16x-1$. Clearly, $\alpha=1$ is a root of the resolvent and furthermore it is different from $0$ and it is a perfect square in $\mathbb Q$. So, you can factor your polynomial as $(x^2+x+\beta)(x^2-x+\gamma)$ (the coefficients of $x$ in these two polynomials are the square roots of $\alpha$, that is , they are $\pm1$) where $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are such that$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\beta\gamma=12\\\beta+\gamma=\alpha+(-8)=-7.\end{array}\right.$$So, you can take $\beta=-3$ and $\gamma=-4$.

Answer (score 5):

We can write $$x^4-8x^2+x+12=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$$

Comparing the coefficients of $x^3,$ $$0=a+c\iff c=-a$$

Comparing the coefficients of $x,$  $$1=ad+bc=a(d-b)$$

$$\implies a=d-b=\pm1$$

Comparing the constants,  $$bd=12$$

If $d-b=1, d=4,b=3$ or $d=-3.b=-4$

What if $d-b=-1?$

Comment: $d=-4 ،b= -3$ , isn't that right?

Comment: @prayersmith, Yes. $$d=-3,b=-4$$  or $$d=4,b=3$$

Comment: @prayersmith, Of course, we need to check which combination of values of $a,b,c$ satisfies the coefficient of $x^2$

Answer (score 1):

I like the following way.
$$x^4-8x^2+x+12=(x^2+k)^2-((2k+8)x^2-x+k^2-12).$$
Now, we need to find a value of $k$, for which $(2k+8)x^2-x+k^2-12=(ax+b)^2$,

for which we need $$1-4(2k+8)(k^2-12)=0$$ or

$$(2k+7)(4k^2+2k-55)=0.$$

Easy to see that $k=-3.5$ is valid.

Indeed, $$x^4-8x^2+x+12=(x^2-3.5)^2-(x^2-x+0.25)=$$
$$=(x^2-3.5)^2-(x-0.5)^2=(x^2-x-3)(x^2+x-4)$$
and we are done!

In the general case we'll get a cubic equation with the variable $k$ and one of this equation roots always gives difference of squares and possibility of the factorization.